# Где ошибка в скрипте php $_POST?

Tags: php, post

```
&hash = sha1($_POST['notification_type'].'&'.
$_POST['operation_id'].'&'.
$_POST['amount'].'&'.
$_POST['currency'].'&'.
$_POST['datetime'].'&'.
$_POST['sender'].'&'.
$_POST['codepro'].'&'.
$_POST['notification_secret'].'&'.
$_POST['label']);
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&', expecting end of file in /home/h54881/public_html/dietiprosto.ru/event/YandexMoney.php on line 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

название переменной

```
&hash // замените на $hash
```